# Puppeteer - Click a button only if exists

Tags: javascript, while-loop, click, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a webscraper in Node, using Puppeteer.
My first challange (which I thought would be easy), it's pass by a pagination "Load more" button.

But, when I run the following code, Puppeteer click on all "Load more" and after click on a content, when I need to stop clicking.

Why this happens?

```
    let loadMore = true;

    while (loadMore) {
        selector = 'ul.pager > li > a.button';

        await page.waitForSelector(selector, { timeout: 600 }).then(() => {
            page.click(selector);
        }).catch(() => {
            loadMore = false;
        });
    }
```

Thx all!

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you're trying to achieve and what is the problem here. I see the code that looks like it tries to load all pages by clicking the `a.button` (which will btw work as expected only if there is only one `ul.pager > li > a.button`). What's the issue here? does it not work after loading a few pages? does it give any specific error?

Comment: Try to add return in `then()`: `return page.click(selector)`. Otherwise, it is resolved with `undefined` not waiting for the click.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this.
I think timeout doesn't make a difference here, if the `await` inside the if's condition is not enough then there could be other problem with the script.

```js
let loadMore = true;
while (loadMore) {
  const selector = 'ul.pager > li > a.button';

  if ((await page.$(selector)) !== null) {
    await page.click(selector);
  } else {
    loadMore = false;
  }
}
```